# "Item is not reviewable" when migrating a question in the close queue

Tags: bug, review

Have a look at this review:

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/review/close/46793

Notice that it says

> This item is not reviewable.

I got an error message when I tried to complete the review (It said something to the effect of "A problem occurred trying to complete this review").  However, it migrated the question to Stack Overflow anyway (my close vote was the fifth one).

Seems like there might be some programming logic happening out of order here, like it is migrating the question (and taking it out of the site's scope) before the review can be completed.